# Erlang Ports vs Nodes when both are written in X, where X in not an Erlang VM language

Tags: erlang, elixir

I have read through the Erlang documentation, in particular the topics regarding [Erlang Ports](http://erlang.org/doc/tutorial/c_port.html) and [Erlang Nodes](http://erlang.org/doc/tutorial/cnode.html).

The tutorial uses the same example to present these two concepts, that of a program serving two simple functions, but despite some communication protocol differences, it does not clarify the advantages and disadvantages of using either concept.

At first sight, it seems that ports are much easier to setup servers in external languages, but I would like to know what Erlang Nodes can offer that Erlang Ports don't, and vice-versa.

Can anyone clarify on the functional and non-functional aspects of Erlang Ports vs Nodes?

Thank you

**CLARIFICATION UPDATE**

What I really want to compare is Erlang Ports vs Node written in non-ErlangVM languages (I know that Erlang Nodes are full Erlang VMs and hence much powerful than Ports). For example, what can a C Port do that a C Node cannot, and vice-versa?

Comment: This is kinda “what’s better, an orange or a table” question. One can think about ports as about “sophisticated sockets” and about nodes as about “sophisticated virtual machines.” The latter might have formers, it might have not. *NB* the analogy is very contrived, but still.

Comment: @mudasobwa I rewrote my question, now it is probably clear what I want to ask.

Comment: My comment does still apply. Node is a codepiece, port is a connector.

Comment: @mudasobwa There is probably a terrible misunderstanding here. What I am referring to an "Erlang Port" is the program in language X behind an Erlang Port ... (not what is a port ...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing that CNode or Port can or cannot do. I think you missed to understand why each option was built, then it may help you decide which to pick.

CNode was built to help with distributing tasks across the cluster. Cluster is why you want this option.

Port was built to replace NIFs in case when there is existing linux device, command line tool or script available to accomplish task for you. You still can build erlang cluster since you erlang application will call port after all :) so you are not limited with this option.

Now imagine you have huge C/C++ e.g. postgres database, and you want to make it part of your cluster (dumb example but bear with me). You can fork source code, add CNODE code to it and transform RPC messages into queries, and event more, you can use postgres internal API which you wouldn't be able to have with just SQL queries. So port wouldn't be that helpful in this case since it is some external service running but ...you could build some extension in pstgresql, then expose it to SQL as some function and finally make standard SQL query in order to execute such function from erlang node.

As I said, each has it own place, it really depends what is your case and what existing solutions you have available and need to incorporate into your solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, nodes were designed to distribute services across the physical machines in a cluster, whereas ports were designed to use the services of command-line alike tools running in the local machine. Still you said `"You still can build erlang cluster since you erlang application will call port after all :) so you are not limited with this option."`; how can this be done with a port? would it be to have the port forwarding messages to another program running in another machine in the cluster?

Comment: Your erlang app will start in NODE anyways since that app will call some non erlang app trough port. Once app started and you started port, you can simple do `net_adm:ping('some_app@on-other-host').` and you are in the simplest cluster. Depends what you need, you can forward messages from other nodes in erlang cluster to port and vice versa.

Comment: I believe you are saying that any other Erlang application in a cluster can reach a port anywhere in that cluster through the Erlang node that created the port ... this is nice to know.

Comment: It seems that the most important difference is that, from the point of view of a particular Erlang VM instance, a Node is an application anywhere in the cluster, whereas a Port created by that instance can only be created in the same machine as the instance.

Comment: In nut shell they are 2 different things, NODE either Erlang or C node primarily are built for clustering, ports and NIFs are built for interoperability with other languages. What is making confusion is that NODE can be written in other language too

Comment: Thank you for your clarifications.